# AngularJs Input radio value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a form where a user has to say if he is `male` or `female`. In my database it's a `1` or `0`. How could I make this with AngularJs `input radio`.

Right now I've got this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Radios</label>

    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="radio radio-primary">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="male" id="male" ng-model="employeeCtrl.employee.Gender" ng-value="0"><span class="circle"></span><span class="check"></span>
                Male
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio radio-primary">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios4" ng-model="employeeCtrl.employee.Gender" ng-value="1"><span class="circle"></span><span class="check"></span>
                Female
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this is not working. The right radio button is not selected also the value won't change.

Comment: Try change `name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios4"` to  `name="male" id="female"`

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/radioButton

Comment: Thanks that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the code and see is this what you expect.
Use same name for radio button, and you can use different id for each controller.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="">
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Radios</label>

      <div class="col-md-10">
          <div class="radio radio-primary">
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" id='gender_male' name="gender" ng-model="employeeCtrl.employee.Gender" ng-value="0"><span class="circle"></span><span class="check"></span>
                  Male
              </label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio radio-primary">
              <label>
                  <input type="radio" id='gender_female' name="gender" ng-model="employeeCtrl.employee.Gender" ng-value="1"><span class="circle"></span><span class="check"></span>
                  Female
              </label>
          </div>
      </div>
    Gender: {{employeeCtrl.employee.Gender}}
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```